# URL Downloader asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a windows app with C#.net to download a file from the internet

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        prbPercent.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblPercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }

    private void btnPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog s = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        s.ShowDialog();
        txtPath.Text = s.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

        int t1 = txtLink.Text.LastIndexOf('/');
        string strFileName = txtLink.Text.Remove(0, t1 + 1);

        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(txtLink.Text), txtPath.Text + "//" + strFileName);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

but I'm looking for how to I write something like that with asp.net MVC

I want to do it with website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And, why exactly is this tagged with “java”?

Comment: actually I changed it but  I don`t know  why it didn`t...!